# Submitting complex JSON to MVC controller. How do I name nested objects?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a controller set up that's expecting this object to be posted to it:

```
public class PrintJob
{
    public string BarTenderFile { get; set; }
    public string PrinterName { get; set; }
    public List<TagLabel> Queue { get; set; } 
}

public class TagLabel
{
    public string Season { get; set; }
    public string STSStyle { get; set; }
    public string VStyle { get; set; }
    public string ColorCode { get; set; }
    public int CODI { get; set; }
    public string SizeDesc { get; set; }
    public string StyleDesc { get; set; }
    public string ColorDesc { get; set; }
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public long UPC { get; set; }
    public double CurrRetail { get; set; }
    public double OrigRetail { get; set; }
    public string AvailableIn { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to submit to my controller via AJAX using JSON to represent my object. It works fine for the top level attributes of `PrintJob`, the controller sees the values for both the `BarTenderFile` and `PrinterName` attributes. The problem is the `Queue`. My javascript looks like this:

```
var queue = [];

$('#queue tr').each(function () {
    var tagLabel = $.parseJSON($(this).find('pre').text());
    queue.push(tagLabel);
});

var data = {
    "BarTenderFile": $('#btFile').val(),
    "PrinterName": $('#printer').val(),
    "Queue": queue
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: window.submitQueueUrl,
    dataType: "application/json",
    data: data,
    success: function (returnVal) {
        // Do success stuff
    }
});
```

The JSON for each `Queue` object is stored within hidden `<pre>` tags on the page, formatted so that each name matches the names in my `TagLabel` object. I figured this would be easier than using scads of hidden input fields. The JSON being sent generates no errors and the back end code digests it without issue. The problem is when I submit this to the controller the `Queue` is populated by a list of `object`. The end result is, in my controller, the `Queue` will have however many queue items I selected but each queue item is populated by nulls and zeroes. How do I tell my controller to recognize each queue item is a TagLabel instead of a generic object?

Comment: You aren't sending JSON, change the `data:` to `data: JSON.stringify(data),`. Also `dataType` specifies the response type not the type you're sending (`contentType`).

Comment: The data looks pretty good, but can you post what `tagLabel` looks like?

Comment: @MrCode /headdesk. Of course that was it. Put that as an answer and I'll mark it. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expanding on my comment: the data isn't being encoded into JSON. jQuery will try to build normal URL encoded data from the objects (this explains why the first part is received).

Change to encode the JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType : 'application/json' // also set the content type
    ...
});
```